# How do i solve a conversion error while building a stack of objects?

Tags: c++, oop, object, stack

Hello i've recently started using classes and i'm trying to build a stack of objects. 
I've created the class Oggetto, which has a int variable and two char* variables(and basic functions like get/set), and i have to use a dynamic array to build the stack.

This is the header file for the stack, but i get this error:

> ```
> [Error] cannot convert 'Oggetto**' to 'T {aka Oggetto*}' in assignment.
> ```
>
> What's the problem and how can i solve it?

```
#include "Oggetto.h"

typedef Oggetto *T;

class Pila
{       

    public:
        Pila():dim(10),riemp(0){ vett =new T[dim];}
        Pila(int d){dim=d; riemp=0; vett=new T[dim];}
        void push(T);
        void pop(T&);
        bool full();
        bool empty();
        ~Pila() {delete []vett;}
        void stampa();
    protected:

        int dim;
        T vett;
        int riemp;
};
```

Comment: ***Where*** do you get the error? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: You typedef'd `T` as `Oggetto*` not as `Oggetto**`.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear enough. I get the error on the two constructors of the class Pila , if you need i can post the other files with the class Oggetto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your member variable has type `T vett`, whereas you assign a value of type `T[dim]` (which is equivalent to `T*`;

Change your member variable definition to

```
T* vett;
```

and it should work.

BTW: using `typedef` just to define a pointer to a well known type usually makes the program less readable and error messages less comprehensive.

So I'd suggest to write

```
Oggetto **vett;
```

and

```
vett = new Oggetto*[dim]
```

Comment: I suspect the typedef is because the professor is slowly building up to templates. It's also possible that the typedef should be `typedef Oggetto T;` but hard to be sure from the information given.

Comment: @john: yes, probably the only reason why aliasing a concrete type name `Oggetto` with an obfuscated/shortended/abstract type name `T` makes sense.

Comment: @StephanLechner Thank you for your answer^^.
The reason why i put typedef Oggetto* T is that we were instructed to implement the stack with a dynamic array. Is it wrong to define it like this?

Comment: No, it's not wrong. As it's about implementing a stack on your own (probably without using std::vector), then `vett Oggetto **` is OK, and `typedef Oggetto* T; vett *T` means exactly the same as `vett Oggetto **`.